# Grep end regex matching

Tags: sed, grep, perl

On OS X, `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` outputs:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory: 8 GB
```

I want to get the `Memory` value, trimmed of whitespaces.

This is what I had:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep --color=never -E '^ +Memory: ' | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Not ok. It keeps the whitespace.

I switched to this:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | perl -ne 'if(/^ +Memory: (.*)$/){print $1;}'
```

and I'd like to ask:

- Could this be made more concise in Perl?

The braces annoy me, often I type them wrong. Having to put the condition in `()` is also bothersome. The semicolon is bothersome.

- Could this be made as concisely using more basic UNIX tools? (grep/sed/awk)?

Note: I do not use this line I like..

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | sed -Ene 's/^ +Memory: (.*)$/\1/g p'
```

because extended regexes (`-E` are `-r` on some platforms? possible?) and fundamentally because, although I understand that `sed` works on lines, `-n` suppresses output unless I explicitly `p` print it, `s//g` is a normal regex `substitute`.. and that commands following a `match` are only executed on matching lines.. I am puzzled by the fact that `s//g` in reality is an action in itself.. so I would expect `p` to require a `;` before it.. odd that you can both replace and use the match as a condition to execute the comand.. is that line correct at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk would make it most consise:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk  -F': ' '/Memory:/{print $2}'
```

Comment: Does not capture the unit of measure, in that case GB, which was desirable.. perhaps a capture "from field 2 to NF"? How would you write that?

Comment: Not sure, so I simply edited the answer to use a proper -F parameter :)

Comment: This is the best I have found anywhere. The -F to include both the colon _and_ the space trims the rest of the line already, in one go. Very compact, exactly right.. LIKE!

Answer (score 0):

This is all you really need for the Perl one:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | perl -nle '/ry:\s*(.*)/ && print $1'
```

Some other choices:

- `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | /bin/grep Me | gawk '{print $2,$3}'`

  Using /bin/grep eliminates the need for `--color=never`. `grep` is defined as an alias to `grep --color=auto` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (at least it is on most Linux distros and, I guess, on OSX).
- `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | /bin/grep  Me | /bin/egrep -o '[1-9]+.+'`

  The `-o` causes grep toprint only the matched characters.
- `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4,5`
- `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*: //g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | sed -n 's/^ *Memory: //p'
```

`p` here is a flag to the `s` command (like `g`), not the `p` command, and means print the pattern space if the substitution takes place. You don't need `g` here, since the pattern can only match once.